# Exposing Entity Framework ENTITY classes to Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have some Entity Framework entity classes in their own assembly and they are shared amongst WCF and clients like asp.net and WPF. It works as it should :-)

Problem is now I need to share this assembly with Silverlight - please note I am not using RIA services and I am unable to use ria services as I am locked into wcf services. I know with RIA services it's transparent but I don't have this option.

Considering that it's not possible to share (as far as I know) assemblies created in .net with Silverlight - how do I get the Entity classes into Silverlight (client) .. actually I am using POCO (Entity Framework 4).

Comment: Entity classes will appear on a client side if you choose Add Service Reference.

Comment: Anyway you can create a Silverlight assembly with poco-classes and add cs-files in .net assembly as links.

Answer (score 0):

I have an article that talks about the solutions.  [Sharing code between Silverlight and .NET](http://devtreats.com/sharing-code-between-silverlight-and-dotnet/)